# ZipEntry changes UpperCase filename to CamelCase

Tags: java

I am trying to zip up 3 files in a windows environment just before SCP'ing them to a Linux server.
The 3 filenames are all uppercase.
When I add the ZipEntry to the ZipOutputStream, it changes the file name to camel case.  This will not work when sending them to Linux.
Is there any way to keep the uppercase names when I use ZipEntry.putNextEntry()?

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
String strOutFile = "MyZip.zip";
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(strOutFile);
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
String strInFile = "FILE1.TXT";
ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(strInFile);
zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(strInFile));
int len;
while ((len = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
  zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
```

Comment: Changing a name automatically from upper case to camel case is not possible as this would require the knowledge what a word is (to get the boundaries when a new upper case letter is required). Therefore it more likely that you only see the upper case name but the real name is camel case or the other way round. Use an hex editor and check the real file name in the zip file (it should occur twice).

Comment: @Robert
I am not trying to convert the file names to camel case.  They are being converted to camel case when added to the ZipEntry but I want them to remain upper case.

Comment: You don't understand. Your code is correct and the created ZIP file is correct (I tested the code). Only the ZIP viewer you use is lame and shows file-names that have only upper-case characters to 1st character upper-case and the rest lowercase (which is btw not CamelCase!). Use a correctly working ZIP tool like WinRAR as viewer and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Now I understand.  I confirmed using 7-Zip that the files are actually upper case.  Thank you.